# How to remove the "select all" in react-table?

Tags: reactjs, react-table, react-table-v7

I am looking the following example. However, i would want to remove the "select all" in the table header. What should i do? Thanks

https://codesandbox.io/s/github/tannerlinsley/react-table/tree/master/examples/row-selection

Comment: Are you talking about the checkbox that selects all rows? If so, then remove `<IndeterminateCheckbox>` from `Header` (line 78 in **App.js** in your sandbox).

Comment: @tromgy Thanks. I think i know how to remove it dynamicly.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to define Header. You can achieve your effect by removing the Header.

Answer (score 0):

Updated: just add a props then,

```
 Header: ({ getToggleAllRowsSelectedProps }) =>
            showSelectAll && (
              <div>
                <IndeterminateCheckbox {...getToggleAllRowsSelectedProps()} />
              </div>
            ),
```